# Correlation between Sweat and fat burning

Tags: weight-loss, body-fat, burn-fat, sweat

I was wondering about the place of your body where you sweat more during  workout and fat burning, Is there any correlation between them ? 
For example, Having more sweat around your belly, means you are burning fat from your belly  ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is an indication that you are burning some calories but there is no definite relation between fat burning and sweating. You may sweat while you are burning fat or you may sweat while you are using carbs as an energy sources but since you have sweat around your belly it does not necessarily mean that you are burning fat from your belly. Fat burning is not happening locally, by the way. In addition, environmental conditions also affect sweating ratio.